# show blob instead of original path in website by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, blob

In my website I need to show many videos. so currently I show it like

`<video src="www.example.com/video/video_name.mp4"></video>`

but I don't want to show original path because it is not good for security. so want to show blob instead of path like (generally we can see it in youtube videos.)

`<video src="blob:http://website.info/ag678uyij665-zqq1-221v-b6d3-4vrr4j63dt6c></video>`

Also its possible to have big sized video too.

so I want a js function which can convert my original path to blob, which I can show to my website. also it cant be fetched by passing it to url.

Anyone can suggest if there is any alternative too.

Comment: "because it is not good for security" — What aspect of security concerns you?

Comment: "so I want a js function which can convert my original path to blob," — How are you running the JS? Node.js? Classic ASP? Something else?

Comment: I want normal javascript or may be jquery

Comment: By "normal" do you mean "running client side in the browser"? So you want to stop the browser getting the real URL by giving the browser the real URL and then applying JavaScript? How is that going to work?

Comment: Using client-side languages for security issues is not the best idea.

Comment: on loading page it will not show video... user has to click on button to see video. that time I want to show blob instead of original path...
and also you can suggest for  better option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do that on the client side. That's not possible. You have to make your server handle the desired URLs.

Comment: we put a button and on click we show video... still its not possible?

Comment: No, you have to do this on the server.

Comment: so any suggestion?

Comment: Take your server code or configuration and make it handle whatever url you want to send it.

Comment: In short that path should be accessible within my site and can't open video even after pass it to url.